# In script, calculate floating point with high precision, and store in shell variable value with a lower precision

Tags: bash, shell

In a script of mine, I compute a variable `mflow` from another variable `folder`. The computation must be performed at high accuracy, but then the final result must be truncated to one significant digit. Currently I'm doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash


for folder in 100 115 116 117; do

    temp=$(bc <<< "scale=20;$folder/100*14.8")
    mflow=$(bc <<< "scale=1;$temp*1/1")

    echo $mflow

done

exit 0
```

It works fine. However, line

```
mflow=$(bc <<< "scale=1;$temp*1/1")
```

seems a bit of a waste. Is there a way to perform the intermediate computations at high accuracy, AND assign the result to `mflow` with a chosen (lower) accuracy? Of course, I don't want to sacrifice the readability of the script too much. Thus, please, not a solution that looks like one of those `sed` "one-liners from hell" ;) (ok, I guess `sed` couldn't be used for this, but you got my point).

PS in case someone wonders why I don't just write

```
mflow=$(bc <<< "scale=1;$folder/100*14.8")
```

just try that modification in the script and see what happens (the last three values of `mflow` become equal, which creates issues down the script workflow).

Comment: As much as I understand `$(bc <<< "scale=20;$folder/100*14.8")` is returning a string so maybe you could simply take a substring?

Comment: @Dziugas, no, that's not a good idea. I want to round to the closest fp with specified accuracy, not just truncate. In other words,if I have 17.5757, I need 17.6, not 17.5.

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood your requirements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of awk for the calculation and output formatting:

```
for folder in 100 115 116 117; do
        awk -v f="$folder" 'BEGIN{printf "%.1f\n", f/100*14.8}'
done
```

Thus, it gives:

```
14.8
17.0
17.2
17.3
```

If you want to have more precise result printed, you could change `%.1f` into `%.20f`, then you have:

```
14.80000000000000071054
17.01999999999999957367
17.16799999999999926104
17.31599999999999894840
```

### Note:

If you picked `bc`, you should know this "feature":

```
kent$  echo "scale=1;17.17777/1"|bc  
17.1
```

It will give you `17.1` instead of `17.2`. I hope you knew this before picking `bc` as your tool.

Comment: I want to learn from the downvote... can the downvoter leave some comment, please?

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and it works. I have modified your second line to `mflow=$(awk -v f="$folder" 'BEGIN{printf "%.1f\n", f/100*14.8}')`, because I need to store the result of the computation in a variable, but other than that, the code works fine.